# Which adjective can I use to express the contrary of net?

Tags: adjectifs, antonyme, word-request

I read this in an [article](https://www.linxea.com/assurance-vie/gestion-libre-nos-allocations-type/) on Lixea.com titled « Comment sont distribuées les allocations ? »

> Les performances annualisées affichées sont *nettes* de frais de gestion du contrat.

Which adjective can I use to express the contrary of *net* in that context?

Answer (score 7):

**Brut**.

See [Larousse online](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/net/54328):

> net, nette
> (...)
> 4. Se dit d'une quantité qui n'a à subir aucune retenue, par opposition à brut : Bénéfice net.

> brut, brutte
> (...)
> 2. Par opposition à net, qui n'a pas subi certaines déductions, certains ajustements : Salaire brut.

That use of net/brut applies to all sorts of ''monetary sums'', typically to indicate pre-tax or post-tax (income, price, revenue etc.). While Larousse indicates it could apply to any "quantity", I fail to imagine a case where it applies to anything else than money.

Furthermore, most uses of brut/net in that context exist within technical expression with a fixed meaning as to what deductions apply: for instance ["résultat net"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9sultat_net) has a specific accounting meaning.

---

The usual meaning of "brut" is "raw, rough" (which is close to its "accounting" meaning). By extension, ''une brute'' means a brutish person (in spite of gender stereotypes, ''une brute'' is a feminine word, just as ''une sentinelle'' [a watchguard]).

The usual meaning of "net" is ''clear, focused''; it can be used both in the literal sense (a photograph is clear/sharp, a window is well-cleaned), and a figurative sense.

Example from the [opera ''Carmen''](http://opera.stanford.edu/Bizet/Carmen/acte3.html) (from 1875; the language is maybe a bit formal, but entirely correct in modern metropolitan French). The torero has come to a smuggler’s hideout to court Carmen (the title character), and is stopped by a guard who is in fact her current lover:

> *José*
>
> Mais pour nous enlever nos filles de Bohême / savez-vous bien qu'il faut payer ? / (...) Et que le prix se paie à coups de navaja! / (...) Comprenez-vous ?
>
> *Le torero*
>
> Le discours est très net.

> *José*
>
> To woo away our Bohemian girls; do you know well you have to pay? And the price is paid in blows of navaja! Do you understand? *[A navaja is a [folding knife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navaja); José is challenging the torero to a duel]*
>
> *The torero*
>
> The speech is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Similairement à une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52450/26366) :

> Qui est dépourvu, exempté de quelque chose : 8 % d'intérêt net d'impôts. ([Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/net/54328))
> **Net de.** Dépourvu de, exempt de. *Ciel net de brumes.* ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/net))

Antonyme :

> Les performances annualisées affichées sont *brutes de* frais de gestion du contrat. [voir par exemple [ici]](https://www.linxea.com/tout-savoir-sur/assurance-vie/fonds-euros/)